# deleting multiple rows via checkbox

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to delete multiple rows using checkboxes however I don't seem to get it work. Can someone show me what I am missing or what would be better approach?

I am trying to delete the rows using their id. I am getting the below notice and nothing is being set to `yes` in deleted column

`Notice: Array to string conversion in`

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php
$result = $stmt->get_result();
echo"<div class='message'>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

?>

<div class='msgwrap'>
<input name="checkbox[<? echo $row['id']?>]" type="checkbox" ><?php echo $row['to_user'];?>

</div>

<?php

}

?>
<input type="submit" name="delete">
</div>
</form>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
$id = $_POST['checkbox'];  
$mydb = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', '');
$stmt = $mydb->prepare("update messages SET deleted ='yes' where to_user = ? and id = ? ");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $user, $id);
$stmt->execute();}
?>
```

Comment: If I had to guess, check that your $user is a string, not an array

Answer (score 0):

PHP is automatically converting your checkboxes' POST value to an array, due to the fact that you are using array notation in the `name` attribute.  Try something like this:

```
$ids = implode( ',', $id );
$stmt = $mydb->prepare("update messages SET deleted ='yes' where to_user = ? and id IN(?) ");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $user, $ids);
```

It's not clear from your code where `$user` is coming from.

Comment: I have defined `$user` but didn't include it here.. Your code is giving me `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$id'`

Comment: thanks but now it throws `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bindParam()` when I hit submit and doesn't set to `yes`

Comment: Sorry, I was using PDO functions.  Updated for mysqli.

Comment: No luck throws `Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference`

Comment: Updated again.. must store the result of `implode` in a variable and pass that since `mysqli::bind_param` accepts the parameters as references